# How to use a while loop within a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that return results that are based on year the user inputs. Say the user chooses a start year of 2016 and an end year of 2018, the stored procedure will loop though those years to return results. However, I only need the select to loop through a few columns for this.

For example, I'm looking for something similar to the logic behind the below.

```
SELECT 
    column A, column B
    WHILE (@CurrentYr <= @MaxYr)
    BEGIN
        ,CASE WHEN(Year = @CurrentYr THEN, columnC)
        SET @CurrentYr = @CurrentYr + 1
    END
FROM 
    Table1
```

which would return columns

```
ColumnA, ColumnB, 2016's ColumnC, 2017's ColumnC, 2018's Column8
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use a `WHILE` *inside* a statement; it's a logical flow operator. It looks like the real problem is you have a denormalised design and have a column for each year. If you fix your design, you don't have this problem. If you won't, then you'll need to go down a dynamic SQL approach; which just makes things far harder than they need be.

Comment: @Larnu I think actually they have a normalized design but are trying to created a denormalized output. They want a new column for each year in the result.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into a dynamic cross tab to accomplish what you want here.  I can help you if you can post some consumable data and desired output.

Comment: Possibly, @SeanLange . Without meaningful sample data, and expected results, very difficult to know. Even if that is the case, it'll still need dynamic SQL, which I would suggest is a path the OP doesn't go down. If they want a dynamic pivot, they would be (in my opinion) better off doing this in their presentation/reporting layer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample that creates a temporary table "#MyTemp" with the base columns and then has a loop to add additional columns for the years based on your current year and maximum year variables.  After each column is added with the dynamic SQL you can then update that column with data using additional Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @YearCurrent int
DECLARE @YearMax int
DECLARE @YearCounter INT
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Sql varchar(100)

SELECT @YearCurrent = 2018
SELECT @YearMax = 2021

SELECT SettingID AS ColumnA, SettingValue AS ColumnB
INTO #MyTemp
FROM ApplicationSetting

SELECT @YearCounter = @YearCurrent
WHILE @YearCounter <= @YearMax
BEGIN
   SELECT @ColumnName = 'Year_' + CAST(@YearCounter AS VARCHAR(20))
   SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #MyTemp ADD [' + @ColumnName + '] VarChar(100) NULL '
   PRINT @SQL
   EXEC ( @SQL )

   SELECT @SQL = 'UPDATE #MyTemp SET ' + @ColumnName + '= OrderHeader.SomeColumn FROM OrderHeader WHERE #MyTemp.ColumnA = OrderHeader.ColumnA'
   PRINT @SQL
   EXEC ( @SQL )

   SELECT @YearCounter = @YearCounter + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #MyTemp
```

I am not sure what you want to put in the year columns but the update statement gives you the basic idea and you can adjust the update statement as needed.

Sample Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `WHILE` within a `SELECT` statement. However, here is a pattern that may help you build a dynamic one:

```
DECLARE @CurrentYr int = 2019, @MaxYr int = 2021, @sql varchar(MAX);

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT columnA, columnB, ' + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG (
            CASE YearIncrement
                WHEN 0 THEN CONCAT ( 'columnC AS Year_', @CurrentYr + YearIncrement )
                WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT ( 'columnD AS Year_', @CurrentYr + YearIncrement )
                WHEN 2 THEN CONCAT ( 'columnE AS Year_', @CurrentYr + YearIncrement )
                -- WHEN...etc
            END
            , ', '
        ) AS cols
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) - 1 AS YearIncrement
        FROM STRING_SPLIT ( ( SELECT REPLICATE ( ',', @MaxYr - @CurrentYr ) ), ',' )
    ) AS x
)
    + ' FROM Table1;';

PRINT @sql;
```

**PRINTS**

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC AS Year_2019, columnD AS Year_2020, columnE AS Year_2021 FROM Table1;
```

By using a combination of

- `REPLICATE` (creates a list of commas based on the difference in years)
- `STRING_SPLIT` (splits said comma list into rows)
- `ROW_NUMBER` (provides a number (-1 to start the increment at zero) to add to each year over said rows)
- `STRING_AGG` (combines them all back into a comma-delimited list)

we can create a dynamic SQL statement that may be executed. Unfortunately, I am unaware of a workaround for the `CASE` conditions as your column names will vary.